# Confusion in this step of backpropagation derivation

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, neural-networks

I was look at the derivation of backpropagation equations and i couldn't understand a certain step.

[image: Here is the image highlighting the step]

Why do we need that sigma term?
[Here is the link to the full derivation](https://github.com/chrismbryant/backpropagation/blob/master/2017_06_21%20Backpropagation%20Derivation%20(for%20Coursera%20ML).pdf)

Thank you!